# Confused about a complex sentence

Tags: complex-sentences

In John Seely's Oxford A–Z of grammar and punctuation, he gave the following sentence as an example of a complex sentence:

> She told him that she did not play again for over a week.

'She told him' is the main clause and 'she did not play again for over a week' is the subordinate clause, according to him.
My question is how this subordinate clause is dependent on the main clause? To me, the main clause feels dependent and the subordinate one seems independent. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "dependent".

Comment: It's the direct object of the verb _told_. Being dependent is not a matter of feeling; it means that it's not a complete sentence as it stands; in this case, _that she did not play again for over a week_ is not a complete sentence; it's a subordinate (non-main) clause.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking without the that.

Comment: Yes, it is complex, but "she told him" is just part of the main (matrix) clause, which in your example is the whole sentence. The clause _that she did not play again for over a week_ is marked as subordinate by the subordinator "that". And, of course, it cannot stand alone as a sentence.